# How to determine if a class contains a subclass / type?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

Can we have a [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE) trick to know, if the class has certain subclass/type. Something like,

```
template<typename TYPE> // searches for "my_type"
struct has_inner_type {
  enum { value = <???> };
};
```

Following are the examples:

```
struct A {
  class my_type {};  // has_inner_type::value = true 
};
struct B { }; // has_inner_type::value = false
struct C { typedef int my_type; }; // has_inner_type::value = true
```

I tried few tricks, but falling short mostly with expected compiler errors.
Usage:

```
bool b = has_inner_type<A>::value;  // with respect to "my_type"
```

**Edit**: I have re-edited my question, as it seems that it's impossible to pass `my_type` as second parameter to `has_inner_type`. So, as of now the question is to find only a specific type as `my_type`. I have [tried this code](http://www.ideone.com/EABWW), which doesn't work.

Comment: You want to know if it has any inner type, or an inner type with a specific name?

Comment: @Martinho, I re-edited my question. I want to find only with specified name. Sorry for inconvenience. @AJG85, the errors are obvious, as I am not finding the right way to implement it. So those errors are not worth mentioning. Still working on it.

Comment: Just change my other code to say `typename T::my_type` instead of `int T::*` and you are set.

Comment: You mean to say like this: http://www.ideone.com/EABWW

Comment: Doesn't the Wikipedia article you link have the working example of just the kind you need?

Comment: @n.m, nice observation. I posted SFINAE link, just for reference (for those whom doesn't know about it). But I didn't care to see the content inside it (though I had seen before). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the answer which was present in the wikipedia link I posted in the question !! (thanks to [@n.m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m).)

```
template <typename T> 
struct has_inner_type
{
  typedef char yes[1];
  typedef char no[2];

  template <typename C> static yes& test(typename C::my_type*);
  template <typename> static no& test(...);

  static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

Here is [the demo](http://www.ideone.com/XK8I2).